# Correct method for instantiating object from String containing class name (with known superclass)

Tags: java

I am trying to create new instances of a class (specifically a subclass of an abstract class) by using the forName(String) method.

For example, if I wanted a subclass of Number:

```
import static java.lang.Class.forName;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

Object[] arguments = new Object[] {0};
String classname = "java.lang.Integer";
try {
 Class<? extends Number> c = forName(classname).asSubclass(Number.class);
 Constructor<? extends Number> constructor = c.getConstructor(Number.class);
 Number x = constructor.newInstance(arguments);
}
catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
java.lang.Integer.<init>(java.lang.Number)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you paste the error / stack trace for those of us who also don't know?

Comment: Unless you have a static import on Class.forName your code won't compile. (for those who try to execute the code)

Comment: Yes sorry, will add that above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`java.lang.Integer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) has not constructor that takes a `Number` as its argument.

Reading the stacktrace that you got would have told you that (possibly in a slightly cryptic way, but the info is there). You should *at least* post the stack trace when you've got a question about it.

Comment: OK, i see. What should I be giving that method considering the input would be a primitave int?

Comment: Click the classname, I linked the JavaDoc. Check which constructors *do* exist for `Integer`. Use one of those.

Comment: Did not realise int.class was valid syntax. Thanks anyway, very helpful